# Getting user selection in a CLI app

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, command-line-interface, clipboard

I'm a big fan of the auto-copy functionality in iTerm 2. Is it possible to programmatically get the user’s selection via Bash/ZSH/Node/Python et al? I'm familiar with using something like pbcopy to hit the pasteboard, but unfamiliar with methods for retrieving the current selection outside of JavaScript or Objective-C.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Where are you trying to get the user's selection? By selection you mean the current/last highlight in the shell?

Comment: Exactly what iTerm 2 does. When a text selection/highlight is made, an event is fired and the highlighted text is copied to the clipboard.

Comment: That's not really an answer to my questions though. You said `iTerm2` already does what you want, right? So where is this not happening that you want it to happen?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? 
"programmatically get the user’s selection via Bash/ZSH/Node/Python"
Where are you trying to get the user's selection? 
"In code for a CLI app. Yargs in Node would be an example."
By selection you mean the current/last highlight in the shell?
"Yes."

Answer (score 0):

You can -- assuming that this is an X-Windows question -- use the `xclip` command to retrieve the current X selection from the command line (or in a shell script).  E.g., something like this:

```
current_selection=$(xclip -o)
echo "Your selection was: $current_selection)
```

The source for `xclip` is [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/), and it is very likely already packaged up for your favorite operating system (on my Fedora box, it is available via the `xclip` package).

Comment: Hi @larsks—I'm not able to see this working on my computer (an iMac), so I can't verify the answer.